# Which resources should be closed?

Tags: java, file, download

I'm trying to download a file from an URL. There are many resources and I dont know which one I need to close or do I simply have to close all of them?

```
    public void downloadUpdate(final String url) {
    try {

        /* Which of these resources do I need to close? */
        final InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
        final ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Bukkit.getServer().getUpdateFolderFile());
        final FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();

        /* Downloading the update... */
        fileChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), move all resources in the resources block and let Java do everythign for you =)

Comment: Already thought about this, but is it really necessary to close every resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, likely the only resources that *need* to be closed are the `InputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. However, why not simply close them all by using try-with-resources? It doesn't hurt to call `Closeable#close()` just in case<sup>1</sup>. In fact, you probably *should* close every `Closeable` in your control (i.e. that you opened) when finished with them (you don't necessarily know if a wrapper also needs to release resources).

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
     ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Bukkit.getServer().getUpdateFolderFile());
     FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel()) {

    fileChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above is not much different than what you currently have.

---

<sup>1. Calling `Closeable#close()` method has no effect if invoked previously. This isn't necessarily true of `AutoCloseable` implementations (that don't implement `Closeable`).</sup>

---

Also, if you're using Java 9+ you don't need to deal with NIO channels. The `InputStream` class had a method added in Java 9: [`transferTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)).

```
try (InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(...)) {
    is.transferTo(fos);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You might also be able to use [`Files.copy(InputStream,Path,CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) (Java 7+).

```
try (InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream()) {
    Path file = Bukkit.getServer().getUpdateFolderFile().toPath();
    Files.copy(is, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note this might not result in the same behavior as when using `FileOutputStream`. I'm not entirely sure if `FileOutputStream#<init>(File)` truncates any existing bytes or if it simply overwrites the bytes from the beginning.

If you prefer using NIO channels, you can open a `FileChannel` directly via [`FileChannel.open(Path,OpenOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) rather than going through a `FileOutputStream`. As I showed in an example above, you can convert a `File` into a `Path` using `File#toPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it should be enough to close `FileChannel`, and it's gonna close `parent`, or [FileDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) (see [java11 sources](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java#L186)) of according resource. Actually, with the same result you can close only `fileOutputStream` and it's gonna release all file resource as well ([source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#L357))

But with that you're relying on the implementation of these closable resources, so the **best practice** is to close each resource you have opened, and easier way to do so is to use [try with resources](https://dzone.com/articles/java-code-bytes-be-resourceful-with-try-with-resou).

Comment: So the best is to close every resource but in theory I could only close the InputStream and the FileOutputStream and every other resource would also be closed?

Comment: In this particular case, if you close, for instance, fileChannel, then fileOutputStream won't be actually closed. But you cannot use it anymore because system resource will be released by fileChannel and in theory it is enough. But the best practice is to close everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, since I'm using Java 8, I'm probably gonna use Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target, CopyOption... options) and just close the InputStream. Otherwise I would've used InputStream#transferTo​(OutputStream out).